# Laravel Socialite does not work when Facebook App "Require app secret" setting is enabled

Tags: laravel-socialite

For security reasons I decided to enable "Require App Secret" on my Facebook App. Then I discovered that Laravel Socialite version "`^2.0`" was not working because it was not sending the appsecret_proof on the method "`getUserByToken`" of the class "`Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider`".

I decided to make a quick fix:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getUserByToken($token)
{
    $appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $token, $this->clientSecret);//THIS IS MY QUICK FIX
    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get($this->graphUrl.'/'.$this->version.'/me?access_token='.$token.'&appsecret_proof='.$appsecret_proof.'&fields='.implode(',', $this->fields), [
        'headers' => [
              'Accept' => 'application/json',
         ],
     ]);

     return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}
```

Are there better solutions for this requirement? Is there an official patch for this use case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now this is solved.
I sent a pull request: https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/100

This pull request is already merged and it is included on release v2.0.12